# multilinguality without localization in android, but via button

Tags: java, android, button, resources, multilingual

my little issue this time is the following:

I want my app to be multilingual.

The user should be able to change the language by a simple button press. for that i created two valuesfolders (`res/values` and `res/values-de`) now my problem is, I do not know how to access them after buttonclick, may you help me?

I do not want to use Localization, it should be solved just by button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is how it is done:**

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.BTN_de) {
            languageToLoad = "de";// german
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.BTN_uk) {
            languageToLoad = "en";// english
        }

        Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        this.getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
        Language.lang();
        finish();
    }
```